# tf.fake_quant_with_min_max_vars is a differentiable function?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, quantization

Quantization schemes are generally non-differentiable because they pass through the threshold, such as round or sign function. It means that we can not get the gradient of trainable variables due to the nature of chain rule.

Instead, we can use a trick called **'straight-through-estimator'**, which enable us to back-propagating the gradient of individual trainable variables.

One such method is **tf.fake_quant_with_min_max_vars**, The advantages of this format are that it can represent arbitrary magnitudes of ranges, they don’t have to be symmetrical, it can represent signed and unsigned values, and the linear spread makes doing multiplications straightforward.[Blog](https://petewarden.com/2016/05/03/how-to-quantize-neural-networks-with-tensorflow/), [Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.05877).

So, my question is, can we differentiate the fake_quant function? And if so, does this function apply 'straight-through-estimator'?

I did a little bit of this with some snippet code

> x = tf.cast(np.random.normal(0,1,(10,10), tf.float32)
>
> x_q = tf.fake_quant_with_min_max_vars(x, min=tf.reduce_min(x), max=tf.reduce_max(x), num_bits=3)
>
> grad = tf.gradients(x_q, x)

In that case, almost every grad have value 1(i.e, gradient 1), which means it pass through the gradient itself.

However, sometimes a few samples have gradient 0, or other constant, such as 2, 3, 4...

Am I missing what's going on?